# Spouse/child family versus parent/sibling family

Tags: kinship-terms

There are times when I need to refer to the family comprised of my spouse and children versus when I need to refer to my family comprised of my parents and siblings.

Are their words to distinguish between these? “Immediate” and “extended” family throw them into the same bucket!

Comment: I do not think that there is a simple answer to this question.  The concept of 'family' is a slippery one, because the word can either denote a strictly biologically related group or to something more subjective than that, involving socio-emotional closeness and interdependence.  Even biologically related people, for example, may have little or no communication, physical or otherwise, with one another for a variety of reasons.  Even the expression 'birth family' is hard to nail down precisely, and the absence of finely differentiated descriptors suggests we just have to be q clear as we can.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, but the answer here is much better than the answers there.

Comment: @Mitch, to some extent, yes, the answer below is more to-the-point and offers terms for both sides of the distinction. *Family of origin*, which is in JAM's answer to the other question is, however, often used for a birth family in psychology and related fields.

Comment: It is important to clarify that the terms that are sought by this question are not terms for different kinds of families, but terms that manifest different perspectives on families.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The family you were born into is called [**Birth Family**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/birth-family) and the family shaped by (after) marriage is referred to as [**Conjugal Family**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugal_family).

**Update:**
To reflect @Edwin and @Paul comments, some other terms (in different contexts) to refer to after-marriage-family are as follows:

- [Family of procreation](https://study.com/academy/lesson/family-of-procreation-definition-and-lesson.html)
- [Blended/Step family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepfamily)

Comment: I'm happy with the definition of 'birth family', but 'conjugal family' seems to refer to any family with married parents, and children.

Comment: [According to Britannia](https://www.britannica.com/topic/conjugal-family), conjugal families are not distinct from, but rather a variety of nuclear families. And according to [another source](https://socialsci.libretexts.org/Courses/Solano_Community_College/SOC_002%3A_Social_Issues_and_Problems/12%3A_Family/12.01%3A_Family) the two terms are synonymous.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum, neither the question nor this answer said anything about nuclear families.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!